# Symfony2 Solarium Class 'Solarium_Plugin_Abstract' not found

Tags: symfony, solarium

I am using https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioSolariumBundle and I am trying to conect with solarium y my symfony2 application.

I have installed solarium with the composer.json but then I get

> Class 'Solarium_Plugin_Abstract' not found in .../vendor/bundles/Nelmio/SolariumBundle/Logger.php on line 12

I don't understand why in the Logger there is:

```
use Solarium_Plugin_Abstract
```

But in the folders I find:

> myproject/vendor/solarium/library/Solarium/Plugin/Abstract.php

I have declared in my `autoload.php`

```
'Solarium' => DIR.'/../vendor/solarium/library',
```

Should't be: use Solarium/Pluguin/Abstract ?

What I am doing wrong?